# Smarty loop getting the array ID/Key

Tags: php, html, arrays, smarty

I am a little new with Smarty and loops, etc. I have this data coming through but need to get the initial ID such as [114], [115] before the child array and not sure how. Any ideas?

I am outputting like so:

```
<pre>{$item2.$childs|print_r}</pre>
```

I need to get the array Key from the print I used, as it is the ID I need to get:

```
<ul class="ty-menu__submenu-list cm-responsive-menu-submenu">
    {if $item2.$childs}
        {hook name="blocks:topmenu_dropdown_3levels_col_elements"}
        {foreach from=$item2.$childs key="i" item="item3" name="item3"}
            {assign var="item3_url" value=$item3|fn_form_dropdown_object_link:$block.type}
            {assign var="item3_id" value=$item3[id]|fn_check_is_active_menu_item:$block.type}
            <pre>{$item2.$childs|print_r}</pre>
            <li class="ty-menu__submenu-item{if $item3.active || $item3|fn_check_is_active_menu_item:$block.type} ty-menu__submenu-item-active{/if}{if $item3.class} {$item3.class}{/if}" data-mm-id="{$item3_id}">
                  <a{if $item3_url} href="{$item3_url}"{/if}
                        class="ty-menu__submenu-link">{$item3.$name}</a>
            </li>
        {/foreach}
        {if $item2.show_more && $item2_url}
            <li class="ty-menu__submenu-item ty-menu__submenu-alt-link">
                <a href="{$item2_url}"
                   class="ty-menu__submenu-link">{__("text_topmenu_view_more")}</a>
            </li>
        {/if}
        {/hook}
    {/if}
</ul>
```

Print of array

```
Array
(
    [114] =&gt; Array
        (
            [new_window] =&gt; 0
            [item] =&gt; Butterfly Sofa Bean Bags
            [href] =&gt; categories.view?category_id=114
            [level] =&gt; 2
        )

    [123] =&gt; Array
        (
            [new_window] =&gt; 0
            [item] =&gt; Avatar Lounger Bean Bags
            [href] =&gt; categories.view?category_id=123
            [level] =&gt; 2
        )

    [115] =&gt; Array
        (
            [new_window] =&gt; 0
            [item] =&gt; Twin Couch Bean Bags
            [href] =&gt; categories.view?category_id=115
            [level] =&gt; 2
        )

    [116] =&gt; Array
        (
            [new_window] =&gt; 0
            [item] =&gt; Versa Table Bean Bags
            [href] =&gt; categories.view?category_id=116
            [level] =&gt; 2
        )

    [113] =&gt; Array
        (
            [new_window] =&gt; 0
            [item] =&gt; Acoustic Sofa Bean Bags
            [href] =&gt; categories.view?category_id=113
            [level] =&gt; 2
        )

    [164] =&gt; Array
        (
            [new_window] =&gt; 0
            [item] =&gt; Twin Ottoman
            [href] =&gt; categories.view?category_id=164
            [level] =&gt; 2
        )

    [136] =&gt; Array
        (
            [new_window] =&gt; 0
            [item] =&gt; Wing Ottoman Bean Bags
            [href] =&gt; categories.view?category_id=136
            [level] =&gt; 2
        )

    [112] =&gt; Array
        (
            [new_window] =&gt; 0
            [item] =&gt; Fiorenze Bean Bags
            [href] =&gt; categories.view?category_id=112
            [level] =&gt; 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was setting a key and outputting like so

```
{foreach from=$item2.$childs key=item3_id item="item3" name="item3"}
    {assign var="item3_url" value=$item3|fn_form_dropdown_object_link:$block.type}
    <li class="ty-menu__submenu-item{if $item3.active || $item3|fn_check_is_active_menu_item:$block.type} ty-menu__submenu-item-active{/if}{if $item3.class} {$item3.class}{/if}" data-mm-id="{$item3_id}">
          <a{if $item3_url} href="{$item3_url}"{/if}class="ty-menu__submenu-link">{$item3.$name}</a>
    </li>
{/foreach}
```

output with

```
{$item3_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can able to get the array by like this

```
$array = array(
'9' => array('4','6','8'),
'1' => '2',
'2' => '0',
'3' => '3',
'4' => '1');

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo $mykey = $key;
}
```

Comment: Im using smarty... what would be the way with my code above? thanks for your help